# Is there an ADB Shell command that tells me the contents of a TextView?

Tags: android, automation, scripting, adb

I've been writing this script on Linux in order to automate some parts of the app that I'm working on. My next goal is to get the login process of the app automated, which amounts to clicking a couple buttons and entering a 6-digit code into a separate login page on a website. We're doing this using a combination of ADB shell scripting and a Python script running the Selenium webdriver for the webpages that need to be logged into and whatnot.

This leaves me where I am at now; I found how to input button presses (or rather the "taps" themselves) at specific coordinates using ADB shell commands, so that's half the problem... however, I was unable to find the command required to grab specifically the contents of a TextView for use in my script; it's for the login flow, so I need it to be assigned to a variable in the script, like you would a directory, if possible ...

(i.e. $TEXTCONTENT=****** where *s are the 6-digit code)

... so it can be used later when Selenium webdriver needs to login and enter the 6-digit code. Is there a specific command I'm looking for in order to grab this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use uiautomator here. There is a Python package [uiautomator](https://pypi.org/project/uiautomator/) that can help:

```
from uiautomator import device as d

d(resourceId="id/mytextfield").text
```

Or if you want to do it the more manual way, the screen contents can be dumped to an XML file using `adb shell uiautomator dump`. Then you can `adb pull` it locally, where your script can then parse the XML for the text.

Comment: The command `d(resourceId="id/mytextfield").text` will wait indefinitely regardless of what resource ID I select.

Comment: Actually, after a very long time, it will fail with error: `OSError: RPC server not started!`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to find and interact with the Views.

I don't know the app you are using so my example is based on Calculator.

If you type any number on Calculator and run this script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

vc = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit())
vc.dump()

formula = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.google.android.calculator:id/formula")
print(formula.getText())
```

it will print that number.